# Javascript Haxe member variables Objects

Tags: jquery, object, haxe, member-variables

**Javascript:**

```
function TeamSelection(player_id)
{
     var playerInfo = new Object();
     playerInfo["info_" + player_id];
}
```

**Haxe:**
hey I tried to define object like so:

```
class TeamSelection
{
        var playerInfo    : Map<String>;
        public function new() {}
        public function changeField()
        {
          playerInfo.set("info_" + player_id, player_name);
        }
}
```

But Im getting a compiler error,

what should I do?

Nevo.

Comment: JavaScript is NOT Java.

Comment: Well in javascript i can define object like so
var obj = new Object();
obj['info' + player_id] = player_name;

Comment: Which compiler error do you receive?

Comment: @user3625518 they are two very different languages. Not to mention your question has no JS in it

Comment: You may see that JavaScript has a lot similarities to Java, but both languages aren't same. It's like comparing apples with pears.

Comment: But haxe can compiles to javascript,
so there is gotta be a way to mimic this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/871050

Comment: why do you guys are you talking about java? haxe is a proper langage which have some similarities with java. It makes use of classes and can compile to javascript. the question i perfectly valid.

Comment: @user3625518 The answer postite gave is correct, but you might want to look at this Haxe manual:  https://github.com/Simn/HaxeManual/blob/master/HaxeDoc.pdf?raw=true It's a work in progress but it could help you grasp the key concepts when using Haxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you are triying to do but you have to instanciate your Map

```
class TeamSelection
{
        var player:Player;
        // i don't know why you don't stock your players directly..
        var playerInfo    : Map<String,String>= new Map();// has to be instanciated
        public function new() {

        //create your player
        player= new Player();
        player.id=1;
        player.name="bob";

}
        public function changeField()
        {
          //make use of string interpolation 
          playerInfo.set('info_${player.id}',player.name);
        }
}
class Player{
public var id:Int;
public var name:String;
public function new(){}

}
```